# Calling Multidimensional array with name

Tags: php, arrays

When I was studying about multidimensional arrays all the first attribute in the square bracket is always a number. Can I call it with a key? My multidimensional array is

```
$something =  array (
   array("Volvo",22,18),
   array("BMW",15,13),
   array("Saab",5,2),
   array("Land Rover",17,15)
);
```

I know to access the elements of the array like `$car[0][0]` which prints Volvo .The question is that can I add a string name on the first bracket section `$car['key']['key']`
Is it possible in PHP arrays ??..I think that cant be done with the array which I mentioned. It will be really helpful if you give me an example on which how to access multidimensional array like `$car['key']['key']`

Comment: if you want to access your array like that you can just build them by associative keys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[PHP: Array](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)

Multi-dimensional key => value arrays can be declared similar to this example:

```
$something = array(
    "car1" => array("Volvo", 22, 18)
    // ...
);
```

Then accessed with:

```
$something["car1"];
```

---

**UPDATE**

You're describing adding yet another dimension to your array:

```
$something = array(
    "cars" => array(
        array("Volvo", 22, 18),
        array("Audi", 0, 1)
    )
);
```

If you'd want to access an item within the "`cars`" sub-array, you'd do so like:

```
$something["cars"][0];
```

Comment: i know how to do this but my question is different ..i need to call like $something['key']['key'] ..2 keys with 2 brackets ..

Comment: @user3619803 Check my edit. Does it match what you are attempting to accomplish? You may want to read up on [Arrays in PHP](http://php.net/array)

Comment: but when i called $something['cars'][0];..it gives me error

Comment: @user3619803 Because you're not using the number `0` to represent the element in the array anymore, you're using a string. To access it, utilize the string representation of the array element: `$something["cars"]["Volvo"]` (see answer)

Comment: i understand the way of acessing keys ..i want to acess like $something["cars"][0]

Comment: @user3619803 If you want to access it just like that, then remove the string from the key declaration. I have updated my answer.

Comment: can you update you answer to show in which situation do i wanna call $something["cars"][0] ..it will be really helpful..

Comment: @user3619803 As I mentioned in my previous comment, I did already update my answer to reflect your specific needs. You _REALLY_ should read the [PHP manual page regarding Arrays](http://php.net/array)

Answer (score 0):

Yah PHP Allow Key as String Value for Multidimensional Array. I have ReStructured your Given Array for Your Requirement.

PHP Array

```
<?PHP
$something =  array (

    'Volvo' => array('title' => "Volvo",22,18),

    'BMW'   => array('title' => "BMW",15,13),

    'Saab'  => array('title' => "Saab",5,2),

    'Land Rover' => array('title' => "Land Rover",17,15)

 );
?>
```

Print The Value though String Key.

```
<?PHP 
$something['Land Rover']['title'];
 ?>
```

Output:

```
Land Rover
```

**UPDATE**
For your Given Requirement! the possible Array Structure is:

```
 <?PHP
   $something =  array (
            'cars' => array(
                    "Volvo",
                    "BMW",
                    "Saab",
                    "Land Rover"
                          )
    );


    echo $something['cars'][0];
?>
```

Output

```
Volvo
```

Comment: i understand the way of acessing keys ..i want to acess like $something["cars"][0]